# How do I play a .wav file in Java without it halting my program?

Tags: java, wav

I was able to make the .wav file to play, but when it play, it halts the program (depending where it is placed) and then lets the program to resume. I'm wondering if I am able to prevent this and have it play while the rest of the program is executing. Does anyone know any specific methods that I would have to try to get this working? I'm not asking for you guys to write it for me; I just need to know if there are more efficient methods (tried google but I wasn't able to find anything). Any help is appreciated! :)

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;


public class CharacterCreator extends JOptionPane
{
   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
      File Sound = new File("badapple.wav");

      String name, ageStr, gender, finalName, femaleAge, maleAge, femaleGender, maleGender,     fileCreated, error;
      int age, again;

  do
  {

     //Initiates .wav file
     PlaySound(Sound);

     name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your character's name?");

     gender = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Is your character female or male?");

     ageStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How old is your character?");
     age = Integer.parseInt(ageStr);


     finalName = "Your character's name is " + name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1);

     if (gender.matches("female|Female|FEMALE"))
     {
        femaleGender = "Your character is a female!";
        femaleAge = "She is " + age + " year(s) old!";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, finalName);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, femaleGender);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, femaleAge);
     }

     else if (gender.matches("male|Male|MALE"))
     {        
        maleGender = "Your character is a male!";
        maleAge = "He is " + age + " year(s) old!";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, finalName);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, maleGender);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, maleAge);
     }

     fileCreated = name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1) + "'s file has been created!";

     PrintWriter out;
     try
     {
        out = new PrintWriter(name + ".txt");            
        out.println("******************************************");
        out.println("**                                      **");
        out.println("** WELCOME TO YOUR CHARACTER'S PROFILE! **");
        out.println("**                                      **");
        out.println("******************************************");
        out.println("");
        out.println("Name: " + name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1));
        out.println("Gender: " + gender.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + gender.substring(1));
        out.println("Age: " + age);
        out.close();
     }

     catch (FileNotFoundException e)
     {
        System.err.println("File doesn't exist");
        e.printStackTrace();
     }


     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, fileCreated);

     again = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do Another?");
  }

  while (again == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);
}

static void PlaySound (File Sound)
{
  try
  {
     Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
     clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Sound));
     clip.start();

     Thread.sleep(clip.getMicrosecondLength()/1000);
   }

   catch (Exception e)
   {
     System.out.println("Cannot find or play sound!");
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Remove the Thread.sleep() in the PlaySound() method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove this line.

```
Thread.sleep(clip.getMicrosecondLength()/1000);
```

Also, you might want to consider multi-threading if you are going to read files from the disk.

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
 JOptionPane jop = new JOptionPane(null);
```